# Bash double bracket regex comparison using negative lookahead error return 2

Tags: regex, bash, regex-lookarounds, square-bracket

On Bash 4.1 machine,

I'm trying to use "**double bracket**" `[[ expression ]]` to do REGEX comparison using "**NEGATIVE LOOKAHEAD**".

I did "`set +H`" to disable BASH variable'`!`' expansion to command history search.

I want to match to "**any string**" except "**arm-trusted-firmware**".

```
set +H
if [[ alsa  =~ ^(?!arm-trusted-firmware).* ]]; then echo MATCH; else echo "NOT MATCH"; fi
```

I expect this to print "MATCH" back,
but it prints "NOT MATCH".

After looking into the return code of "double bracket",
it returns "2":

```
set +H
[[ alsa  =~ ^(?!arm-trusted-firmware).* ]]
echo $?
```

According to bash manual,
the return value '2' means "the regular expression is  syntactically  incorrect":

> An  additional binary operator, =~, is available, 
>   with the same precedence as == and !=.
>   When it is used, 
>   the string to the right of the operator is considered 
>   an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).
>   The return value is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.
>   If the regular expression is  syntactically  incorrect, 
>   the conditional expression's return value is 2.

What did I do wrong?

In my original script,
I'm comparing against to a list of STRINGs.

When it matches, I trigger some function calls;

when it doesn't match, I skip my actions.

So, YES, from this example,

I'm comparing literally the STRING between 'alsa' and 'arm-trusted-firmware'.

Comment: You don't have the correct syntax for negative lookahead, it's `(?!arm-trusted-firmware)`. But it doesn't matter, because `bash` doesn't use PCRE, and doesn't support lookarounds.

Comment: woops~ that's my typo on the web.

Comment: Thought it might be, since you made a point of turning off history substitution so you could use `!`.

Comment: So `bash just doesn't support 'lookarounds'.
Is there any other command line tool support 'lookarounds'?
like sed,awk,or grep?

Comment: `grep` with he `-P` option to use PCRE.

Comment: But why not just invert the sense of the test? `if [[ alsa !~ ^arm-trusted-firmware ]]`

Comment: In my original script, I retrieve both the `$STRING` and `$REGEX` from 2 files: `if [[ "$STRING" =~ ^$REGEX$ ]]; then echo "MATCH"`

I was hoping I can achieve this by editing REGEX file only (edit `.*` line to exclude my `arm-trusted-firmware`)
without touching the script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default bash POSIX standard doesn't supports  PCRE. ([source: Wiki Bash Hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression))

As workaround, you'll need to enable `extglob`. This will enable some extended globing patterns:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
```

Check [Wooledge Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for reading more about `extglob`.

Then you'll be able to use patterns like that:

```
?(pattern-list)   Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
*(pattern-list)   Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
+(pattern-list)   Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
@(pattern-list)   Matches one of the given patterns
!(pattern-list)   Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

More about extended BASH globbing at [Wiki Bash Hackers](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) and [LinuxJournal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing).

Comment: Thanks this works~
`shopt -s extglob`
`if [[ alsa  == !(arm-trusted-firmware) ]]; then echo MATCH; else echo "NOT MATCH"; fi`: this **MATCH**.
`if [[ arm-trusted-firmware  == !(arm-trusted-firmware) ]]; then echo MATCH; else echo "NOT MATCH"; fi`: this **NOT MATCH**.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you seem to be confusing globbing and regexp.

Comment: BTW, there's not much point in asking questions of downvoters. They aren't notified when you post comments, so unless they come back to the question of their own accord, they'll never see it.

Comment: @RickLiu Since this answer uses globbing, not regexp, how will it help you with the script you described in your comment above? The file you get `$REGEXP` from contains regular expressions, not globbing patterns.

Comment: What's your point? That section explains pattern matching, also called globbing, not regular expressions. That's why the option that enables it is called `extglob`.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the answer from @Barmar

`BASH` doesn't support "**lookaround**" (**lookahead** and **lookbehind**)

> `bash` doesn't use `PCRE`, and doesn't support **lookarounds**.

Answer (score 0):

Respectfully, aren't you over-complicating things?

```
if [ "$alsa" = arm-trusted-firmware ]
then
  echo 'MATCH'
else
  echo 'NOT MATCH'
fi
```

If you have a good reason for wanting to use the Bashism `[[`, it would serve
you better to provide an example that justifies it.

[Bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Conditionals)

Comment: My original case is to compare a list of STRINGs,

when it matches, it will trigger some function calls,

when it doesn't match, it skips.

And now I want to make exclude case for "arm-trusted-firmware".

Comment: So, YES
i compare the STRING 'alsa' literally
against to the STRING 'arm-trusted-firmware' literally.