# Bash lookahead regex for git commit messages does not work "^[A-Z](?!.*ed).*$"

Tags: regex, bash, git

I am trying to enforce a certain message format for git commit messages.
The regex should enforce that the message starts with an uppercase character and the first word is an imperative.

I am currently using this regex: `^[A-Z]\(?!.*ed\).*$`

Valid:

- Add new file
- Update character model

Invalid:

- Added new file
- add new file
- added new file
- updated character model
- update character model

Although all only regex tools seem to accept this regex, bash does not.
The `ed` exclusion part seems to be the problem: `(?!.*ed)`

Does bash regex not support negative look ahead?

This is my bash script:

```
msg="Add new file"

if [[ $msg =~ ^[A-Z](?!.*ed).*$ ]]; then
    echo "Correct"
else
    echo "Wrong"
fi
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no lokahead in bash

Comment: Please have a look at this answer => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905017/bash-double-bracket-regex-comparison-using-negative-lookahead-error-return-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep -P`, which uses Perl regexes:

```
for msg in 'Add new file' 'add new file' 'Added new file' ; do
    if [[ $( grep -Pc '^[A-Z](?!.*ed).*$' <<< ${msg} ) != 0 ]]; then
        echo "Correct: ${msg}"
    else
        echo "Wrong: ${msg}"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
Correct: Add new file
Wrong: add new file
Wrong: Added new file
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-c` : Print count of matching lines.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

Comment: Turns out my regex did not exactly match my intent, as I wanted to assure that only the first word isn't using past tense. However with this method it was easy to change it to: ^[A-Z](?!\w*ed).*$ which will also correctly allow sth like (excuse the nonsens msg content): 'Add new file for delayed debug logging'. With this change it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

BASH regex doesn't support lookahead assertions.

However, there is no need to use any lookahead here. You can do this using BASH glob matching:

```
[[ $msg = [A-Z]* && $msg != *ed* ]]
```

Comment: Thanks this would work for the specific examples. but it would also filter anything that containes the characters "ed" anywhere in the text I guess. I should have included an example for this case though - my bad. It needs to also accept strings like: 'Add new file for delayed debug logging'

Comment: You can match anything like [[ `$msg = *'Add new file for delayed debug logging' * ]]`.